# Problems in AgendaControl and some Questions

Tags: java, javafx, jfxtras

I got some Questions about the Agenda Control of JFXtras and I hope, any1 can help me.

1. I'm using the CalendarPicker for switching the weeks of the Agenda. In my case, it's only working at every second click on the specific day. It seems, that the Calendar Object of the agenda (agenda.getDisplayedCalendar()) is null at this case. I dont know why.
   [See Exception here](http://s7.directupload.net/images/140722/vv6hnjeh.png)
2. I want to override the method or listener, which is responsible for dragging an appointment to another day or time span. I cant find the location of it in the code. I also saw the recent post for this, but I dont't know, where I need to set a ChangeListener on it

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

For the first a bug on the project would be the correct place. I'm monitoring those and not stackoverflow (maybe I should start).

Since Agenda only expect a list of objects implementing the Appointment interface, you have to catch changes to the end date & time in your implementation. Of course you can use the available default implementation and then you can register to the endCalendar property.